# Is the javascript function "$find" specific for telerik client objects in asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, telerik

As pointed out by the question i am wondering wether the javascript function "$find" is only working because it's provided by telerik controls, or if it's actually a webforms thing i can use.

I know $get is a shortcut for document.getElementById, but i was wondering wether $find is provided by webforms. If so i would be highly interested in how to register a client object to a specific control id.

I've used scriptControl.find("id") for my custom ones so far (where scriptControl is provided by me). But if there's a more standard way of making all client objects accessible through $find i would prefer that.

EDIT:
Digging through MS Code with the help of firebug revealed this:

```
function Sys$_Application$findComponent(id, parent) {
/// <summary locid="M:J#Sys.Application.findComponent" />
/// <param name="id" type="String"></param>
/// <param name="parent" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <returns type="Sys.Component" mayBeNull="true"></returns>
var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
  {name: "id", type: String},
  {name: "parent", mayBeNull: true, optional: true}
]);

if (e) throw e;

return (parent ?
 ((Sys.IContainer.isInstanceOfType(parent)) ?
   parent.findComponent(id) :
   parent[id] || null) :
   Sys.Application._components[id] || null);
}
```

Doing something like

```
Sys.Application._components["id"] = {clientobject};
```

seems like a rather hacky solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `$get` and `$find` are not Telerik-specific. They are included in the ASP.NET Ajax library. `$find` is a shortcut for `Sys.Application.findComponent(id, parent)` ([reference](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/clientreference/Sys/ApplicationClass/SysApplicationFindComponentMethod.aspx)), so feel free to use it as long as this library is included on the page. For instance instead of

```
scriptControl.find("id")
```

you can do

```
$find("id")
```

Note that `$find` is only searching among already registered components, i.e. those added to the Application instance with `Sys.Application.addComponent(component)` method.

Comment: Will $find("id", scriptControl) result in registering scriptControl findable through $find? Otherwise it may have been a bit misleading. currently i'm creating and registering my client objects within the closure hidden behind scriptControl. scriptControl itself is not the client object i am trying to register

Comment: @AndreasMüller,for some reason I thought `scriptControl` is the parent control whithin which you are searching. `$find` is not going to register anything, but the trick here is to realize that `$find` is only searching among components, i.e. elements that were added with `addComponent` method

Comment: Yeah. I only just read this in your reference. Seeing how i'm not deriving from Component i guess i will have to live with calling it the way i'm used to. injecting it into Sys.Application._components might just cause trouble otherwise. Thanks for your help!

Comment: To add to that answer - IScriptControls (based on MS AJAX) create a reference in the DOM object of the element they are created over. Each such control needs an element like this:
<div id="controlClientID"></div>
so you can access such controls like this
document.getElementById("controlClientID").control
which is equivalend to 
$find("controlClientID")
Note that controlClientID is the ClientID from .NET and is likely to differ from the ID attribute of the control.